# XLSX Writer Line chart is not coming as expected

Tags: python, pandas, plot, xlsxwriter

I am plotting a line chart for the below data using XLSX writer. My partial data set is given below. It contains a total of 93 rows.
Please see the obtained plot after running my code. (Present in the Bottom)
My code is given below. Please see my expected output(In the top). May I know where I went wrong?

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('RT_FT.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
TT_PIVOT.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz')
TT_PIVOT_3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TT_3.07_Mhz')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz']
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.set_x_axis({'num_font':  {'rotation': 45}})
chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=(TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$A$4:$A$64,TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$B$4:$B$89,TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$C$4:$C$93)',

    'values':     '=(TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$D$4:$D$93,TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$E$4:$E$93,TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$F$4:$F$93,TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$G$4:$G$93,TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$H$4:$H$93,TT_0.4_2.4_Mhz!$I$4:$I$93 )'
})

worksheet.insert_chart('P20', chart)
writer.save()
```

[image]

[image: Data Set]

[image: Obtained Plot]

[image]

Comment: The values and category ranges in your example don't look correct: they seem to refer to different numbers of points. I'd suggest creating the chart you want in Excel and then copy over the range formulas.

Comment: I updated the code, but still, the output is the same. I am expecting 4 curves in the chart.

Comment: If you need 4 curves/series then you need to add 4 series to the chart. You current example only adds on series.

Comment: okay let me try,will update you

Comment: Now it is coming as expected .thank you, but X-axis is not coming properly.I am expecting 3 parameters in X-axis.

Comment: It should just be a matter of creating an example of what you want to do in Excel and then copy the value and category ranges/formulas to the XlsxWriter program. XlsxWriter will give exactly the same results as Excel if you use the same input data and chart ranges.

Comment: Thank you.May I know how to put variables to 'categories' and 'values': Currently I am entering the range manually